# Xamarin UITest iOS can't reach webview elemtents

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, uitest

I seem to have an issue with detecting elements within webview on iOS, android seems fine.

[image]

When I call for tree to see visible items I get results, however whenever I try querying for any of the items I get no results. I have tried:

```
app.Query(c => c.WebView().Css("fullPage")) 
app.Query(c => c.WebView().Css("#fullPage")) 
app.Query(c => c.Marked("#userNameArea"))  
app.Query(c => c.Id(("#userNameArea"))
```

I also tried using xPath with the same result.:

```
app.Query(c => c.XPath("//userNameInput"))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the genius that down-voted that question. Enlighten me why did you do it?

Comment: I upvoted to counteract the troll. :) I am having issues get a WebView to be found in both Android and iOS. Not sure why! It's my login screen (AzureAD B2C) so i can't really test my app unless I figure it out! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who came across similar Issue on iOS you have to call for Class instead of WebView itself. In my case I had to do:

```
app.Tap(c => c.Class("BrandU_iOS_AuthenticatingWebViewRenderer").Css("#userNameInput"));
```